# powermail (flexform) limitation

Tags: typo3, powermail, flexform

I am trying to extend `powermail` with an own extension.

I created a form for events and there is a field, where that can be filled with the number of the members, who want to join.
In TYPO3 backend I added a plugin setting field "Max Limit".
I want to count all members and compare with "Max Limit".
And the form should not show itself or show a page with information, as soon as the total number of members are more than Max Limit.

I searched in internet for while and I found a documentation about `Finisher` and `Dataprocessor`, but I don't know how exactly I should use them?

Can someone give me any tipp for that?

Answer (score 0):

I would simply overwrite the template file for the formular output and add a custom viewhelper which checks for your contraint. If the contraint is active, render your custom html, else render the powermail formular.

Comment: but how and where could I compare the Values? and the total nummer of members should sum first! and then compare.

Comment: Inside your custom ViewHelper Class. If that VH returns true or false is up to you. You have all freedom there. See the docs https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/8-Fluid/8-developing-a-custom-viewhelper.html